# Чат Laravel vue js.Как обновить информацию только у одной отрисованной записи

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

При прочтении сообщения срабатывает событие что сообщение прочтено .Как обновить уже у веденного списка сообщений что оно прочтено?

```
<template>
    <div class="feed" ref="feed">
        <ul v-if="contact">
            <li v-for="message in messages" :class="`message${message.to == contact.id ? ' sent' : ' received'}`" :key="message.id">
                <div class="text">
                    <p v-html="message.text"></p>
                    <span v-if="message.read==0 && message.to==contact.id" >{{message.read}}</span>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Не очень понятно. VUE реактивен. Если в объекте messages у конкретного сообщения меняется значение read, то в списке у конкретного элемента поменяется значение и он обновится. Видимо в вашем случае при срабатывании события "прочтения", необходимо `messages[номер сообщения].read = 1`